# SKAction doesn't seem to be behaving like I expect

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I have a bunch of actions that I am sequencing together and then running X amount of times. First I wait 0.05 seconds, then I play a sound file, then I add a node to the screen and randomize the sound file for the next time around. However, when I run this, the sound that gets played is the same file for every iteration. If the iterating portion and adding nodes to the screen works, how come the sound wont randomize each time through?

```
    var iterator = 0
    var sound = "Content/text\(RandomInt(1, max: 5)).m4a"

    let waitAction = SKAction.waitForDuration(0.05)
    let addNode = SKAction.runBlock({
        text.addChild(letterNodes[iterator])
        iterator += 1
        sound = "Content/text\(RandomInt(1, max: 5)).m4a"
    })

    let sequenceAction = SKAction.sequence([waitAction, SKAction.playSoundFileNamed(sound, waitForCompletion: false), addNode])
    let repeatAction = SKAction.repeatAction(sequenceAction, count: letterNodes.count)

    runAction(repeatAction)
```

Comment: is the issue in the iterator variable?

Comment: When you create an action, you can only re-use it. You can't modify it in the way you want.

Comment: @bearacuda13 No the iterator variable is working fine, it seems the issue is where I reinitialize the sound variable

Comment: @Whirlwind But the iterator variable is being modified, how come the sound variable isn't? Also, is there a way I can achieve this effect then?

Comment: I will show you why in short... Not currently in front of a computer.

Comment: @Whirlwind Alright thanks. I hope there's a workaround though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not following exactly your code, and it is also Swift 3, but this example does next:

It adds nodes from index 0 to 2, so first node that will be added is white, then purple and brown comes.

Also sounds will be randomized each time. I guess that is what you wanted to achieve.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    let letterNodes = [

        SKSpriteNode(color: .white, size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)),
        SKSpriteNode(color: .purple, size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)),
        SKSpriteNode(color: .brown, size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)),

        ]
    var iterator = 0


    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {


       let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2.0)

       run(SKAction.repeat(SKAction.sequence([wait,SKAction.run(spawn)]), count: letterNodes.count))

    }

    func spawn(){

        let file = "\(GKRandomDistribution.init(lowestValue: 1, highestValue: 5).nextInt()).wav"

        let sound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed(file, waitForCompletion: false)

        let addNode = SKAction.run({[unowned self] in

            let node = self.letterNodes[self.iterator]
            node.position.y = CGFloat(GKRandomDistribution.init(lowestValue: 50, highestValue: 60).nextInt())
            self.addChild(node)
            self.iterator += 1
        })

        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([sound,addNode])
        self.run(sequence)

    }
}
```

A difference between your and mine code is that you were creating a sound action once, and you were reusing it. I create new sound action every time. The code is tested and it is working. You can easily convert it to your Swift version and try it, so when you figure out how this works, you will be able easily to adopt it to your needs.